# Help In understanding Multi Dimentional Arrays

Tags: java

I have been googling a lot to get tutorials to understand from 3-D arrays going but it seems all the tutorials are in 2-D arrays. So i need a little explanation to understand from 3-D arrays going.

I really understand 2-Dimensional arrays very well but am finding it hard to understand 3 and 4 etc dimensional arrays. I know that 2-D arrays stands for rows and columns but what about this 3-D arrays:

My understanding of the code below is that there should be 3 rows and 4 columns but the 5 at the last position makes it look different. I need help in understanding why there are 12 rows and 5 columns. And also if you can help me in understanding 4 or 5-D arrays

Thanks.

```
 class ThreeDMatrix

{

public static void main(String[] args) 

{

int threeD[][][] = new int[3][4][5];

int i,j,k;

for (i=0; i<3; i++)

for(j=0; j<4; j++)

for (k=0; k<5; k++)

threeD[i][j][k]= i*j*k;


{

for(i=0; i<3; i++)

for(j=0; j<4; j++){

for (k=0; k<5; k++ )

{

System.out.print("-" + threeD[i][j][k]); 

}

System.out.println();

}

System.out.println();

}

}
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
-0-0-0-0-0

-0-0-0-0-0

-0-0-0-0-0

-0-0-0-0-0

-0-0-0-0-0

-0-1-2-3-4

-0-2-4-6-8

-0-3-6-9-12

-0-0-0-0-0

-0-2-4-6-8

-0-4-8-12-16

-0-6-12-18-24
```

Please sorry for the poor rendering of the code. I don't really know how to use the code tags properly. If someone will show me then i will repost . thanks

Comment: In the column at the right hand side of the message editor you can see formatting rules and a link to a complete formatting reference. In a nutshell, to format code, just prefix with 4 spaces, or select code and press `010101` button or `Ctrl+K` key.

Answer (score 5):

You can see your three dimensional array as 3 bidimensional array of 4x5 elements, or 12 one dimensional array of 5 elements.

That's why you have 12 rows in your output.

Think about this array as an `int[12][5]` where the first index depends on two different indices. This thing applies also to n-dimensional array. It's just a matter of indices..

If you really need help imagining it you should first consider a bidimensional array, in your example a 4x5 array.. so you have something like

```
00 01 02 03 04
10 11 12 13 14
20 21 22 23 24
30 31 32 33 34
```

when you add a third dimension is like having multiple matrices that stay one on each other..

so if you have `int[2][4][5]` you'll have

```
first index == 0

00 01 02 03 04
10 11 12 13 14
20 21 22 23 24
30 31 32 33 34
```

and another one

```
first index == 1

00 01 02 03 04
10 11 12 13 14
20 21 22 23 24
30 31 32 33 34
```

Maybe this picture can clarify:

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/02e7z943.ArrayExDimThree%28en-us,VS.90%29.gif))</sub>

Every sheet extracted from the "solid" represents a 2D array, infact as you can see every sheet has the same first index (`0` for the first, `1` for the second, and so on). So by specifying the first index you select a matrix, then you can select the precise element by using the other two indices.

Of course you can extend this to any dimension, but it would be more difficult to show you a hyper-solid that represents the array.

Comment: Thanks so much for the picture. I will have a look at it later but thanks in advances

Comment: +1 Awesome answer. For the next dimension, just visualize it as containing n solids. So if the solid above was a block of wood, the next dimension would allow multiple blocks of wood. The dimension after that might represent boxes that contain those blocks of wood. The next dimension could represent something like "trucks" that hold multiple boxes that contain blocks of wood, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`int foo[][][]` declares an array of arrays of arrays of `int`. Each new "dimension" just means "take whatever I have, and get me an array of those". Whether you call them "rows", "columns" or whatever is entirely up to you.

In your example, you see 12 lines because an effect of your nested loops is that you call 12 times `System.out.println()`. 12 newline characters mean 12 lines. This does not relate to the structure of the array, only to the way you print the data.

Answer (score 0):

:-)
There are three groups of sub-groups of four, each with 5 integer. Each line in your printout is a sub group of 5 integer. Four successive lines make one group. If you add a "-" at the second System.out.println your printout would be easier to read